# Create a statically typed variant in C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, variant, template-meta-programming

I am wondering, if it's possible in C++0x to create a statically typed variant, (that behaves like auto) :

```
variant<int, bool, std::string> v = 45;
```

When we assign v to a value other than int, it doesn't compile:

```
v = true; //Compile error
```

So far I haven't found any elegant solution.

Comment: do you want to prevent the compilation of `v = true;` or is the issue that it does not compile ?

Comment: Yes I want to prevent the compilation of v = true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code compiles on my machine with Boost.Variant and g++ 4.5 for both C++98 and C++0x. Do you want to implement a variant-type yourself? Then you might look into the Boost implementation.

In the case that you want to /get/ the above behaviour you could do it like this:

```
auto v = 45;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v), bool>
              || std::is_same<decltype(v), int>
              || std::is_same<decltype(v), std::string>,
              "v must be int, bool or string");
```

This should be quite equivalent to what you describe.

The following implements Clintons suggestion:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct has_type;

template <typename T, typename Head, typename... Args>
struct has_type<T, Head, Args...>
{
    static const bool value = std::is_same<T, Head>::value
                              || has_type<T, Args...>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_type<T> : std::false_type
{};

template <typename... Args, typename T>
T&& check_type (T&& t)
{
    static_assert(has_type<T, Args...>::value, "check_type");
    return std::move(t);
}
```

You only need `<memory>` and `<type_traits>` for this and get perfect forwarding and correct behaviour for integer promotion.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it, 
I want to implement this, but unlike the boost solution, my variant can't change it's type.

Comment: Then this is not possible. There is no way you could set an object parameter at compile-time. Why would you want to do that? In fact, the C++0x `auto`-keyword with some additional `decltype`-magic might be what you are looking for, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: filmors solution is pretty much the way to go. If you want it to look nicer, I would suggest "auto v = check_type<int, bool, std::string>(45)". Check_type would simply forward it's argument but static_assert if it is not one of the enumerated types. Creating the check_type class I'm sure is possible, it just requires some template magic.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion above :) C++0x ftw \o/

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is not possible.

After object is created, its static type does not contain any information related with object initialization. Does not matter, int, or bool was used for initialization, type of the variable is the same:

```
variant<int, bool, std::string>
```

Assignment operator may only analyze contents at runtime, and throw exception, if this is needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can do that at compile time.

You could enable or disable a set of assignment operators using enable_if or similar, but would be per type, not per instance. When compiling v = true in one compilation unit, how could we know there what constructor you used in another compilation unit?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, if we use macro with the auto keyword, and check if with static_assert if the type is in the provided type set (with std::is_same or boost::is_same).

Comment: See my (edited) answer. I don't think you could make a macro from that, that behaves like a type.

Comment: @Simon : Perhaps we can make it work sometimes, but not in general. If you have `extern variant<int, bool, std::string> v; v = true;`, how could the compiler know how v is constructed? What if you change the other module later?